# Need to know where StartAction configuration in Visual Studio is stored

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

In Silverlight project, I could right click and choose Properties. In the Debug tab, I can choose Out-of-browser application to debug the application in OOB mode.

Can anybody inform where is this configuration stored? I've tried to search the .csproj file, OutOfBrowserSettings.xml, and AppManifest.xml, but I don't see this configuration.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes are made to the .csproj.user file.

```
 <StartAction>OfflineApplication</StartAction>
 .
 .
 .
 <OutOfBrowserProjectToDebug>YourAppProject</OutOfBrowserProjectToDebug>
```